# How to add authentication token in header in Openlayers VectorTile - ol.layer.VectorTile

Tags: openlayers

I am looking for help to add authentication token as a header parameter such as Bearer - Access token- to the below code. The following link https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/issues/4213 has an example for ImageTile.

```
new ol.layer.VectorTile({
                    source: new ol.source.VectorTile({
                        format: new ol.format.MVT(),
                        url: "tile_url",

                    }),
                    style: function(feature, res) {
                        return new ol.style.Style({
                            stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                                width: 1,
                                color: 'rgba(0, 102, 204)'
                            })
                        })
                    }
                })
```

Answer (score 2):

You should create a function to provide to `tileLoadFunction` option of the [`ol.source.VectorTile`](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.source.VectorTile.html)
Within this function, you will need to make ajax request yourself and add the authentication token required.

Although it's for vector tiles here, it's quite similar to principles to [one of my previous answer for WMS case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50471595/openlayers-4-load-wms-image-layer-require-authentication/50477911).